# What mood is "if I were" in?

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses, inflectional-morphology, mood, irrealis-were

[Wikipedia says about English subjunctive mood:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English)

> In Modern English, the subjunctive is realised as a finite but tenseless clause where the main verb occurs in the bare form. Since the bare form is also used in a variety of other constructions, the English subjunctive is reflected by a clause type rather than a distinct inflectional paradigm

Doesn't "the main verb occurs in the bare form" mean "be" ("eat", "have" etc.) rather than "were" (or any other conjugation of the infinitive)

So according to this Wikipedia article "if I were" is not conjugated according to the subjunctive mood, if I've understood it correctly.

Please can someone help me understand what grammatical "tense" (I am not sure of the correct terminology here either) that "if I were" belongs to.

Comment: *MODERATOR NOTE:* Answers go in the Answer Box, not the Comment Box.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134335/discussion-on-question-by-theonlygusti-what-mood-is-if-i-were-in).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source

Comment: @Chenmunka I mean it's dead correct in this case. That page is about Wikipedia not being allowed to be used as a citation by Wikipedia article writers, which makes hella sense. What nonsense would that kind of self-referential information source be. Wikipedia has always meant to be a collation of other bodies of information. That doesn't mean it's not a reliable source of information for its readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: The mood of *were* in “If I were you” is either *irrealis* or *subjunctive* (*past tense*), depending on which grammarians you listen to.

There is a battle over terminology currently going on among grammarians. Some grammarians refer to the verb in “If I were you” as the past subjunctive (See for example, this [Grammar girl post](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs)), labeling it as past tense and subjunctive mood. Others refer to it as the *irrealis* mood (See for example the footnote [here](http://cola.calpoly.edu/%7Ebkennell/Subjunctive.pdf)). Wikipedia for now seems to have decided to go with the *irrealis* label. For example, in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Variant_terminology_and_misconceptions) on the English subjunctive, the terminology *past subjunctive* for *irrealis* seems to be classified as a “misconception”, rather than as a possibly superseded name, which would be more accurate.

There are advantages and disadvantages of this change in terminology. An advantage is that in contemporary English, the past subjunctive, or *irrealis*, has very little grammatical relation to the present subjunctive, also known as the *mandative subjunctive*.

A disadvantage is that, historically, both the mandative subjunctive and the irrealis are derived from a subjunctive mood that was used much more broadly; you can visualize these as being two small islands that are left of a much larger subjunctive landmass that has been inundated by the rising waters of the indicative.

Another disadvantage is that trying to change terminology inevitably ends up confusing people, even if you have good reasons for changing it. My personal opinion is that the change is too recent for people to be calling one or the other label “wrong”.

Comment: *superseded :-)

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks. It seems that the older I get, the worse I spell.

Comment: supercede is correct

Comment: I like irrealis the most too

Comment: @theonlygusti The fancy verb *supersede* has a (now-)unique morphology in English: its two component morphemes are the very common *super* meaning “above” or “over” plus the **extremely rare** *sede* meaning “seat” or “sitting”. You must have been expecting it to have *cede* meaning “yield” or “give way” or “go” as in *cede, concede, recede, secede, intercede, precede.* We respelled the only other two *sede* verbs we ever had in English, so that former *obsede* became *obsess* and former *possede* became *possess*. We never changed *supersede*, so it’s constantly getting misspelled.

Comment: The fact is that Present-day English does not have a subjunctive mood. It was lost in earlier stages of the language. it's better to call it 'irrealis', a special mood form instanced solely by "were" with a 1st or second person sing. subject. The subjunctive is, then, not a mood but a type of clause headed by a plain form verb, as in "It is vital that I be kept informed". Btw, there's nothing 'past tense' about this "were". Whichever analysis is preferred, it's a mood form, not a tense form.

Comment: @BillJ: You are being inconsistent here. If there's nothing "past tense" about the *were* in *if I were king* (which I would agree with), then there's also nothing "past tense" about the *won* in *if I won the lottery*. So they should ***both*** be called *irrealis*, and the *irrealis* mood is not limited to *were*. Saying that the *irrealis* mood is limited to *were* is like saying that English does not have an imperative mood, just because the imperative and the infinitive always have the same form.

Comment: Of course the irrealis mood is limited to "were” in Present-day English. To claim otherwise would be a ridiculous error. Clauses headed by verbs with a preterite tense expressing a modal meaning, such as the one you cite, are called 'modal preterite' clauses, and the verbs they contain are called 'modal preterites'. And, FYI, ‘imperative’ is a clause type, not a mood, whose verb is in the plain form, just as it is in subjunctive clauses. In Present-day English, mood is mostly marked by modal auxiliaries, the exception being the isolated irrealis mood form “were”.

Comment: Pretty silly to call it a "mood". It's a construction, with specific modes and rules, like every other construction. It reminded people of the Latin subjunctive, and that was good enough, because up until recently, nobody minded confusing words with their meaning. Now that we try sporadically to separate them, it gets confusing to distinguish form from function.

Comment: @BillJ *there's nothing 'past tense' about this "were"* <--- I don't understand your reasoning there.

Comment: @BillJ . *Of course the irrealis mood is limited to "were” in Present-day English. To claim otherwise would be a ridiculous error.* <--- I nearly always agree with you, but here I can't (this is my area of research!). The term *irrealis* supposedly indicates that something isn't true. However, this is ***not*** the actual case with so-called irrealis *were*. The term *modal remoteness* is basically identical to the term *irrealis* in this respect. There is no difference between the use of a modally remote preterite and the use of an irrealis *were*.

Comment: @BillJ The evidence to back this up is that 1) irrealis *were* can **always** be replaced by a preterite form of *be*, and 2), as will be clear from the previous comment, it is impossible to distinguish by either syntax, morphology or meaning the difference between an instance of a plural, modally remote preterite and an instance of irrealis *were*. Irrealis *were* seems morphologically to be past tense, and appears only in environments which grammatically require past tense verbs.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I disagree with what you say, but I recall that you never did accept 'modal preterite' as a valid name for preterites whose meaning is modal rather then temporal. For the rest, I suggest you talk to GKP, after all it's his and RDH's grammar that I (and I thought you) stick to.

Comment: See here for the limitation of the irrealis mood to "be: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=irrealis+were&source=bl&ots=WSFHe_fmx3&sig=ACfU3U0oUwDwvObb0WhRmJVmFR6Umv_ehw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPndvVtJP2AhVaiFwKHeXiAU8Q6AF6BAg8EAM#v=onepage&q=irrealis%20were&f=false)

Comment: And see here for verbs with preterite tense expressing modal meaning, i.e, the modal preterites: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=modal+preterite&source=bl&ots=WSFHe-fqt_&sig=ACfU3U0nxTOSaJi1hOLNF_GPZOGX9_5xcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmxfme25P2AhVIfMAKHQxFBtoQ6AF6BAg5EAM#v=onepage&q=modal%20preterite&f=false). You need to get up to date with modern grammar.

Comment: @BillJ; I don't ***like*** this aspect of the modern grammar—I think it's misguided. I like replacing the term *subjunctive* with *irrealis*, but to me saying that *If I were king* is a different verb form than *If I won the lottery* seems like saying that *I cut class* isn't actually a preterite but is a present indicative being used to indicate the past. Why should the fact that the irrealis is different from the preterite for only one verb mean that this verb has its own special mood that doesn't exist for any other verbs?

Comment: I haven't here got access to convenient paradigms of verb inflection from older stages of the language, but you know that there were more distinctions in earlier stages of the language than there are now. There was nevertheless a good deal of syncretism (i.e. shape-sharing), but this won't have been a problem because the semantic difference between counterfactuality or, more generally, modal remoteness and past time is clear. (CONT BELOW)

Comment: CONT: In the present system, where we don't generalise irrealis (or the ill-named past subjunctive) beyond 1/3 sg forms of BE it is easy to distinguish modal remoteness and past time uses of the preterite. We don't generalise because there would be no way of telling whether “if you were”, with the modal remoteness sense, corresponded to “if I was” or “if I were”.

Comment: Moreover, if we were to say that all verbs had a preterite-irrealis distinction we would be claiming that the massive coalescence of realisational forms that has taken place in the development of English has not produced a change in the system of verb inflection itself, but merely large scale syncretism. It is much more plausible to say that irrealis “were” is an unstable remnant of an earlier system – a system which has otherwise been replaced by one in which the preterite has expanded its use in such a way that it now serves to express modal remoteness as well as past time.

Comment: @BillJ; You have just pointed out the silliest aspect of the CGEL's current definition of the *irrealis*:  the verb *were* is in a different mood in *If I were to be chosen* and *If you were to be chosen*. I don't see any rational way to justify that.

Comment: The "were" in _If you were to be chosen_ is not a mood form, but a modal preterite. I've already explained why the irrealis is not generalised beyond 1/3 sing forms of "be".